# Running akka app in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I'm using the play-plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/play-plugin) in jenkins to clean, compile and build the application, but when I run the application using a managed script (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Managed+Script+Plugin) in jenkins, the app starts and stops immediately without any errors.

Anyone have any clue?

managed script

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# =========================================================================
# Copyright 2014 Rado Buransky, Dominion Marine Media
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ========================================================================
#
#
# Check this blog post I wrote with detailed information:
# http://buransky.com/play-framework/init-d-shell-script-for-play-framework-distributed-application/
#
#
# Script to start, stop and check status of a Play framework application. It requires
# the Play application to be packaged using the "dist" command. Before you run the script,
# you have to set values of NAME, PORT and APP_DIR variables.
#
#         NAME – name of the application, must be the same as the name of shell script
#                generated by Play framework to run the app
#         PORT – port number at which the app should run
#         APP_DIR – path to directory where you have unzipped the packaged app
#
#
# Usage: control.sh {start|stop|status|restart}
#    port - requred for start and restart commands
#
# Example: control.sh restart app-name 9000
#
#
# The script uses RUNNING_PID file generated by Play framework which contains ID of the
# application server process.
#
#
# START YOUR APPLICATION WHEN MACHINE STARTS
# ==========================================
#
# The script uses RUNNING_PID file generated by Play framework which contains ID of
# the application server process.
#
#
# SAFE START
# ==========
#
# After starting the application the script checks whether the RUNNING_PID file has
# been created and whether the process is really running. After that it uses wget
# utility to issue an HTTP GET request for root document to do yet another check
# whether the server is alive. Of course this assumes that your application serves
# this document. If you don’t like (or have) wget I have provided curl version for
# your convenience as well.
#
#
# SAFE STOP
# =========
#
# Stop checks whether the process whose ID is in the RUNNING_PID file really belongs
# to your application. This is an important check so that we don’t kill an innocent
# process by accident. Then it sends termination signals to the process starting
# with the most gentle ones until the process dies.
#
#

# Script arguments (start, stop, restart or status)
COMMAND=$1

# ***********************************************
# *************  Set these variables  ***********

 NAME=Name
 PORT=9001
 APP_DIR=PATH



# ***********************************************
# ***********************************************

# Additional arguments to be passed to the Play application
APP_ARGS=-Dhttp.port=${PORT}

# Path to the RUNNING_PID file containing process ID
PID_FILE=$APP_DIR/RUNNING_PID

# Helper functions
echoProgress()
{
    setColor 6
        printf "%-70s" "$1..."
    resetColor
    return 0
}

echoError()
{
    setColor 6
        #printf "ERROR"
        if [ ! -z "$1" ]
        then
        resetColor
                #printf " [$1]"
        fi
        printf "\n"
    resetColor
    return 0
}

echoOK()
{
    setColor 2
        printf "OK"
        if [ ! -z "$1" ]
        then
        resetColor
                printf " [$1]"
        fi
        printf "\n"
    resetColor
    return 0
}

checkResult()
{
        if [ "$1" -ne 0 ]
        then
                echoError "$2"
                exit 1
        fi
}

setColor()
{
        tput setaf $1 2>/dev/null
}

resetColor()
{
        tput sgr0 2>/dev/null
}

# Checks if RUNNING_PID file exists and whether the process is really running.
checkPidFile()
{
    if [ -f $PID_FILE ]
    then
        if ps -p `cat $PID_FILE` > /dev/null
        then
            # The file exists and the process is running
            return 1
        else
            # The file exitsts, but the process is dead
            return 2
        fi
    fi

    # The file doesn't exist
    return 0
}

# Gently kill the given process
kill_softly()
{
    SAFE_CHECK=`ps $@ | grep [-]Duser.dir=$APP_DIR`
    if [ -z "$SAFE_CHECK" ]
    then
        # Process ID doesn't belong to expected application! Don't kill it!
        return 1
    else
        # Send termination signals one by one
        for sig in TERM HUP INT QUIT PIPE KILL; do
            if ! kill -$sig "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 ;
            then
                break
            fi
            sleep 2
        done
    fi
}

# Get process ID from RUNNING_PID file and print it
printPid()
{
    PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
    printf "PID=$PID"
}

# Check port input argument
checkPort()
{
    if [ -z "$PORT" ]
    then
        echoError "Port not set!"
        return 1
    fi
}

# Check input arguments
checkArgs()
{
    # Check command
    case "$COMMAND" in
        start | stop | restart | status) ;;
        *)
            echoError "Unknown command"
            return 1
        ;;
    esac

    # Check application name
    if [ -z "$NAME" ]
    then
        echoError "Application name not set!"
        return 1
    fi

    # Check application directory
    if [ -z "$APP_DIR" ]
    then
        echoError "Application installation directory not set!"
        return 1
    fi

    # Check port
    case "$COMMAND" in
        start | restart)
            checkPort
            if [ $? != 0 ]
            then
                return 1
            fi
        ;;
    esac
}

checkAppStarted()
{
    # Wait a bit 
    sleep 3

    # Check if RUNNING_PID file exists and if process is really running
    checkPidFile
    if [ $? != 1 ]
    then
        echoError
        cat $TMP_LOG 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi

    local HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE

    # Issue HTTP GET request using wget to check if the app is really started. Of course this
    # command assumes that your server supports GET for the root URL.
    HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE=`wget -SO- "http://localhost:$PORT/" 2>&1 | grep "HTTP/" | awk '{print $2}'`

    # The same functionality but using curl. For your convenience.
    #HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE=`curl --connect-timeout 20 --retry 3 -o /dev/null --silent --write-out "%{http_code}" http://localhost:$PORT/`

    checkResult $? "no response from server, timeout"

    if [ $HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE != 200 ]
    then
        echoError "HTTP GET / = $HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE"
        exit 1
    fi
}

# Check input arguments
checkArgs
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
    exit 1
fi

case "${COMMAND}" in
    start)
        echoProgress "Starting $NAME at port $PORT"

        checkPidFile
        case $? in
            1)  echoOK "$(printPid) already started"
                exit ;;
            2)  # Delete the RUNNING_PID FILE           
                rm $PID_FILE ;;     
        esac

        SCRIPT_TO_RUN=$APP_DIR/bin/$NAME
        if [ ! -f $SCRIPT_TO_RUN ]
        then
            echoError "Play script doesn't exist!"
            exit 1
        fi

        # * * * Run the Play application * * *
        TMP_LOG=`mktemp`
        PID=`$SCRIPT_TO_RUN $APP_ARGS > /dev/null 2>$TMP_LOG & echo $!`

        # Check if successfully started
        if [ $? != 0 ]
        then
            echoError
            exit 1
        else
            checkAppStarted
            echoOK "PID=$PID"
        fi
    ;;
    status)
        echoProgress "Checking $NAME at port $PORT"
        checkPidFile
        case $? in
            0)  echoOK "not running" ;;
            1)  echoOK "$(printPid) running" ;;
            2)  echoError "process dead but RUNNING_PID file exists" ;;
        esac
    ;;
    stop)
        echoProgress "Stopping $NAME"
        checkPidFile
        case $? in
            0)  echoOK "wasn't running" ;;
            1)  PRINTED_PID=$(printPid)
                kill_softly `cat $PID_FILE`
                if [ $? != 0 ]
                then
                    echoError "$PRINTED_PID doesn't belong to $NAME! Human intervention is required."
                    exit 1
                else
                    echoOK "$PRINTED_PID stopped"
                fi ;;
            2)  echoError "RUNNING_PID exists but process is already dead" ;;
        esac
    ;;

    restart)
        $0 stop $NAME $PORT
        if [ $? == 0 ]
        then
            $0 start $NAME $PORT
            if [ $? == 0 ]
            then
                # Success
                exit
            fi
        fi
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: This looks like the app will quit with the script in the Jenkins runner - hard to say without trying it all, but you could look in the $TMP_LOG file to find out more. I don't think this whole setup is a good idea, BTW. You may want to use Jenkins to build a native package using http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/ - try the server package, and use the managed script to kill the old process, install the new package and ensure its started, so that all the hard work is being done outside of Jenkins.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. This seems A LOT cleaner than what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out jenkins build process kills ANY child process it creates (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller).

So to resolve this issue I had to add

```
export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
```

to the process(shell script) that I wanted to continue running.

Answer (score 0):

Not without seeing a setup, command or some log files. This is not a direct answer, but have you considered using Maven to run the app? This works for akka apps:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.yourapp.Hello</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

---

Edit to answer further comments: Native packager info

A sample build.sbt could look like this:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.SystemV

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis / 1000

name := """my-app"""
maintainer := "Me Me <me@me.io>"
packageName := """my-app"""
packageDescription := "My business logic."
packageSummary := "Test app."
version := s"1.0.0"

name in Universal := name.value
name in UniversalDocs <<= name in Universal
name in UniversalSrc <<= name in Universal
packageName in Universal := packageName.value
serverLoading in Debian := SystemV
```

...blah

```
fork in run := true

publishArtifact in(Compile, packageDoc) := false

publishArtifact in packageDoc := false

sources in(Compile, doc) := Seq.empty

enablePlugins {
  DebianPlugin
  JavaServerAppPackaging
}
```

And this would help you create a native Debian package with `sbt debian:packageBin` which can be controlled on the machine (once installed) with `service <servicename> start|stop|restart`

Comment: let me try and get back to you.

Comment: just fyi, I simply want to run the akka app from jenkins. It seems wrong since jenkins is basically just CI. Am I right?

Comment: When you say run, are you trying to find a way of starting the application on the server and using Jenkins to do it?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i'm trying to do but to no avail.

Comment: So, what's in the managed script? Can you add this information to your question?